# Scroll percentage tracking: How to ensure no breakpoints are missed?

Tags: javascript

I've been using `setInterval()`, running every 1s to check the % of a page that's been scrolled, with breakpoints at 25%, 50%, 75%. and 100% of `document.body.clientHeight`. I've found that this approach works as expected, but sometimes breakpoints are missed depending on how fast the user is scrolling. Most commonly, the 50% and 75% breakpoints don't get fired.

```
var breakpoints = [0, 0, 0, 0];
var myEvents;
var runOnScroll = setInterval(function() {

    var h = document.documentElement;
    var b = document.body;
    var st = 'scrollTop';
    var sh = 'scrollHeight';
    var scrollPct = (h[st] || b[st]) / ((h[sh] || b[sh]) - h.clientHeight) * 100;
    var totalHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    var visibleHeight = window.innerHeight;

    if (scrollPct >= 25 && scrollPct < 50) {
        breakpoints[0] += 1;
        if (breakpoints[0] === 1) {
            myEvents = 'event203';
            interactionLog('scroll breakpoint: 25%');
        }
    } else if (scrollPct >= 50 && scrollPct < 75) {
        breakpoints[1] += 1;
        if (breakpoints[1] === 1) {
            myEvents = 'event204';
            interactionLog('scroll breakpoint: 50%');
        }
    } else if (scrollPct >= 75 && scrollPct < 100) {
        breakpoints[2] += 1;
        if (breakpoints[2] === 1) {
            myEvents = 'event205';
            interactionLog('scroll breakpoint: 75%');
        }
    } else if (scrollPct === 100) {
        breakpoints[3] += 1;
        if (breakpoints[3] === 1) {
            myEvents = 'event206';
            interactionLog('scroll breakpoint: 100%');
            // clearInterval once 100% of page is seen
            clearInterval(runOnScroll);
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

I've tried reducing the interval to 0.5s, since it's pretty clear the 1s interval doesn't accommodate fast scrolling -- but breakpoints are still missed with a smaller interval time.

What's the best way to ensure breakpoints aren't missed?

Comment: Why not just use the scroll event?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to achieve this (intead of using and interval) is to lisen to the window scroll event. THe script will log the percentages defined in `breakpoints` only once. Then when all the breakpoint goals have been reached, the scroll event is removed.

```js
// Variables
var breakpoints = [25, 50, 75, 100];

function checkBreakpoint(event) {
 
 // Variable declaration
 var totalscroll   = document.documentElement.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight, // Total scrollable area
  currentscroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop, // Current scroll
  percentage    = Math.ceil((currentscroll * 100) / totalscroll), // Percentage scrolled
  index         = breakpoints.indexOf(percentage);
 
 // If the percentage is defined in breakpoints or the closest (lower) breakpoint has been reached
 if(index >= 0) {
  
  // (:
  console.log(percentage + '% reached!');
  
  // Removes th breakpoint goal
  breakpoints.splice(index, 1);
  
  // If no more goals to achieve, remove the event
  if(breakpoints.length == 0) {
   window.removeEventListener('scroll', checkBreakpoint);
  }
  
 }
 
}

// Bind the function to the window scroll event
window.addEventListener('scroll', checkBreakpoint, false);
```

```html
<div style="height: 2000px"></div>
```